Access denied error after upgrading to spring boot 3
We recently migrated our app spring boot 3 /http5 and see the error ,
rror="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."
I am able to hit the base url of our endpoint. The error happens when our service makes a call to another service. It works fine with the previous spring version.
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:149)
    at com.fmr.fit.apigee.XtracTokenProvider.retrieveToken(XtracTokenProvider.java:34)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:128)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:241)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:183)

Are there any oauth related changes that needs to be updated in spring boot 3. The earlier version used to work fine.
Thanks
SecurityConfig file :


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity 
class SecurityConfiguration {

    
    @Bean
    UserService emptyService() {
        return username -> {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("no local users");
        };
    }
    
    
    
    /*
     * @Bean
     * 
     * @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1) public SecurityFilterChain
     * actuatorSecurityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
     * {
     * 
     * httpSecurity.securityMatcher("/actuator/**") .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize
     * -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll());
     * 
     * httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
     * 
     * return httpSecurity.build(); }
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * @Bean public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws
     * Exception { http .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
     * .anyRequest().authenticated() ).httpBasic(withDefaults());
     * 
     * return http.build(); }
     */
    
    @Configuration
    public class DisableSecurityConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

            http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()
            );

            return http.build();
        }
    }


    
    
    

    
    
    
      @Configuration 
      public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
      
      @Autowired 
      JwtAuthentication auth;
      
      @Override 
      public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(auth).addPathPatterns("/abc/*"); }
      
      
      
      }
     



